# What's written on the pig?

Tags: traditional-characters

[image]

Hello! Could you please translate those writings on my pig.

Comment: The first three characters are 相知永..., I don't recognize the last one. It must mean something like "To know each other and eternally [...]".

Comment: Thank you! It could be "friends forever"?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads 相知永伴

相知 means knowing each other very well.

永伴 means always together.